# In Typescript, is there a difference between `return x` and `return await x`?

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await

In Typescript, is there a difference between `return x` and `return await x`?

Suppose we have:

```
async function func(): Promise<void> { }

async function option1(): Promise<void> {
    return await func();
}

async function option2(): Promise<void> {
    return func();
}
```

I know that when targeting ES5, `option1()` will require more code.

In ES2015 and ES2016 it will have an additional `yield` keyword.

In ES2017 - it will just appear as-is, with the additional `await`.

1. Is there any logical difference between the two versions?
2. Can they behave differently in some way when executed?
3. Is there a performance difference in ES2015? And in ES2017?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/main/docs/rules/no-return-await.md) could answer your question. I think that typescript is only extra sugar.